# Failed to install homebrew, m1 chip

Tags: macos, homebrew, nvm

[image: error message]

Install half reported this error, online search but failed to solve, ask for help, thank you

I am new to the mac and want to install homebrew successfully.

Comment: you can use [this site](https://quillbot.com/) to rephrase sentences.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

install Homebrew:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

You can check where Homebrew is installed on your system by running the following command in your Terminal:

```
echo $HOMEBREW_PREFIX
```

For apple chipsets it should be in

> /opt/homebrew

Verify that Homebrew is installed and working correctly by running the following command:

```
brew doctor
```

After that, you can try installing nvm again using the following command:

```
brew install nvm
```

Comment: Do you mean reinstall and re-execute the following commands?

Comment: This command：/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Comment: yes reinstall and re-execute.